# What's wrong with usage of word "different" in this particular way/style?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adjectives

[image: Microsoft Word grammar checker highlighting "different types"]Let's consider below sentence for example:

> **Different types** of animals have different types of diseases. For example ...

MS Word suggests I change *different types* to *several/distinct/Diverse types of animals*.

What's wrong with using *Different* word here, I don't understand why it keeps on suggesting same whenever I use *.

Comment: It offended the MS Word gods.  If you don't appease them they will "lose" your document.

Comment: There is a rule of composition that a writer should avoid repeating a distinctive word close to its original instance, especially if the same word is used for different purposes  Here you have repeated "different" in the same sentence; that alarms MS Word. However, your use of "different" is similar in both cases, so you could make an  argument for not changing it. But that's a bit subtle for MS Word.

Comment: @Zan700 it gives same message even without repetition of word Different,check the screenshot I have just attached.

Comment: @saket Yes, you didn't repeat different, but but you didn't use another adjective, so what you basically said was that animals have diseases. You need another adjective to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using **different**. Microsoft has simply put certain rules into its software. In addition to catching typos and obvious grammar mistakes, it tries to "nudge" you into using certain language.

In this case, it likely sees "types" (or "types of animals") and is trying to get you to use more formal language. Using "***different*** *types of animals*" in a scientific paper, for instance, is, I suspect, less common than one of the options it's proposing. (Although, if it does the same thing when that's the only word you type, then it has nothing to do with context at all.)

What I find more strange than the simple fact that it's doing this at all, is that it thinks *several* is better than *different*. I can understand the other two, but not that one.

In the end, there's nothing wrong with **different**—it's just more informal. I wouldn't trust Microsoft's style decisions at more than a basic level. See what it suggests and then accept or ignore it as is appropriate.

Comment: I think "Many different types" sounds more idiomatic.